# Upgrade react-router Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I upgrade `react-router@3.2.0` to `react-router@4.3.1` and I got error:

> Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in
> `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { browserHistory, hashHistory, Router } from "react-router";


<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={hashHistory} routes={getRoutes(store)} />
</Provider>,
document.getElementById("app")
```

Maybe someone knows how to fix this issue?

Comment: You know v4 is very old?

Comment: Yes, I know. When I upgrade to 6.8.0 I get different error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`react-router-dom@4.3.1` doesn't export any `hashHistory` object, so `hashHistory`, and `history` on the router, is undefined. If you are trying to use `react-router-dom@4.3.1` then you'll need to create the `history` object a little differently by importing `createHashHistory` from the `history` package<sup>*</sup>.

```
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'; // * note on history

const hashHistory = createHashHistory();

...

<Router history={hashHistory}>
  <App />
</Router>
```

**** Note:** I didn't need to install `history` as a dependency in my test [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/upgrade-react-router-failed-prop-type-the-prop-history-is-marked-as-required-mzv7io), but if it matters and you do need to list it as a dependency ensure you have `history@4` installed. The latest `history@5` is used with `react-router-dom@6`.*

You could also just import and render the `HashRouter`.

```
import { HashRouter as Router } from "react-router";

...

<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

I did notice several React warnings in the console trying to use such an old version of `react-router` with newer versions of `react`. `react-router` v4 and v5 are generally considered to be the "same version", though I don't recall the specifics that forced them to do a "major" version bump partway through nor do I care to go spelunking for them. Chances are you can go ahead and bump to at least `react-router@5` (*`5.3.4` as of the time of this post*) without any major ill-effects, the code above is the same.

With `react-router@6` came a ***ton*** of breaking changes. Starting with your comment about "When I upgrade to 6.8.0 I get different error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')", this issue is caused by using the low-level `Router` component instead of one of the high-level routers, like `HashRouter`. The `Router` has a couple required props, and `history` isn't one of them. It is the `location` prop being undefined that the router can't read any `pathname` property of.

See [v6 Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string; // <-- REQUIRED!
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;                 // <-- REQUIRED!
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```